# Convert numbers stored as text to numbers

Tags: excel, vba

this code does not seem to work well always when copying currency data from another sheet:

```
Dim myprice As String
myprice =   othersheet.Range("H" & c.Row).Value
ws.Range("C" & r).Value = myprice
ws.Range("C" & r).Style = "Currency"
```

sometimes cells have a warning that "this number is formatted as text"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Excel's "Number Stored as Text" issue can be a bit vexing.

The Help recommendation is to perform a conversion operation by multiplying the value by 1.  In practice, however, you're probably better off checking that myprice is numeric and then proceeding accordingly.

For instance:

```
Dim myprice As String
myprice =   othersheet.Range("H" & c.Row).Value
If IsNumeric(myprice) Then
    myprice = CCur(myprice)
Else
    'Catch non-numeric accordingly
    myprice = "Couldn't convert to number"
End If
ws.Range("C" & r).Value = myprice
ws.Range("C" & r).Style = "Currency"
```

HTH

Answer (score 1):

Try declaring `myprice` as a `Currency`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using NumberFormat of the cell

```
ws.Range("C" & r).NumberFormat = "$#,##0.00"
```

Answer (score 0):

This is working for me:

```
For Each myprice In __your target range here__
  myprice.Value = CDec(myprice.Value)
  myprice.NumberFormat = "0.00"  'or whatever format you wish
Next myprice
```

Answer (score 0):

This code worked for me, to convert cells depending on their contents. It ran fairly quickly for a worksheet with >800,000 cells containing numbers stored as text, with 32-bit Excel 2013 running on a Windows 8.1 machine. It did the job in less than 2 minutes.

```
For Each aCell In ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Working data").UsedRange.Cells
    If aCell.Errors.Item(xlNumberAsText).Value Then
        aCell.Formula = aCell.Text
    End If
Next aCell
```